# Stack around the variable 'libName' was corrupted when loadlibrary and GetProcAddress for msimg32.dll

Tags: c++, com, visual-c++

I am developing a live messenger plugin like MSN Plus.
I will hook into MSN with proxy `msimg32.dll`.
Unlike other samples of proxy `msimg32.dll` in internet, in which exported functions are retrieved in `DLLMain`, since MSDN said that invoking `LoadLibrary` is unsafe in `DLLMain`.
This is confirmed with test, to load system's `msimg32.dll` within `DllMain` of custom's `msimg32.dll` will result in access violation.

My approach is load `c:\windows\system32\msimg32.dll` in one of exported functions, I found this way in dissassamble of MSN plus's `msimg32.dll`.
But I am facing a critical error in function `GetMsimg32FnAddr`, variable `libName` is corrupted when `GetMsimg32FnAddr` returns.

My question is that how to avoid the stack corrupt in my source code.
Furthermore, Is my idea OK about proxy the `msimg32.dll`?

My dev enviroment is:
VS2005, win7 enterprise version, 32bit.
Latest version of Live messenger.
Latest version of MSN plus.

VS2005 report:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'libName' was corrupted.

when `GetMsimg32FnAddr` returns

Following is my source code of proxy `msimg32.dll`.

`msimgproxy.h`:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
#ifndef MSIMGPROXY_H
#define MSIMGPROXY_H
#include <windows.h>
#pragma warning( disable:4273 ) // Silence compiler

//
// Function pointer typedefs for exports we are forwarding              
//
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PFNTRANSPARENTBLT) (HDC,int,int,int,int,HDC,int,int,int,int,UINT);
typedef VOID (WINAPI *PFNVSETDDRAWFLAG)  (VOID);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PFNALPHABLEND)    (HDC,int,int,int,int,HDC,int,int,int,int,BLENDFUNCTION);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PFNGRADIENTFILL)  (HDC,PTRIVERTEX,ULONG,PVOID,ULONG,ULONG);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PFNDLLINITIALIZE)(HINSTANCE, DWORD, LPVOID);

// Function pointer typedef to injected-DLL initialization
typedef void (*PFNINIT) (void); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif 
    //
    // Function protoypes
    //
    BOOL WINAPI TransparentBlt(HDC, int, int, int, int, HDC, int, int, int, int, UINT);
    BOOL WINAPI AlphaBlend    (HDC, int , int, int, int, HDC, int , int, int, int, BLENDFUNCTION);
    BOOL WINAPI GradientFill  (HDC, PTRIVERTEX, ULONG, PVOID, ULONG, ULONG);
    BOOL WINAPI DllInitialize (HINSTANCE, DWORD, LPVOID);
    VOID WINAPI vSetDdrawflag (VOID);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __CPLUSPLUS
#endif // MSIMGPROXY_H
```

`DllMain.cpp`:

```
#include "msimgproxy.h"
#include <tchar.h>

PFNTRANSPARENTBLT   pfnTransparentBlt   = NULL;
PFNALPHABLEND       pfnAlphaBlend       = NULL;
PFNDLLINITIALIZE    pfnDllInitialize    = NULL;
PFNGRADIENTFILL     pfnGradientFill     = NULL;
PFNVSETDDRAWFLAG    pfnVSetDdrawFlag    = NULL;
PFNINIT             pfnInit             = NULL;

bool        GetMsimg32FnAddr();
HMODULE     hMsimg32 = NULL;
HMODULE     hPlugDll = NULL;

TCHAR pszInjDllName[] = TEXT("msg_plugin.dll");

/************************************************************************/
/*                                                                      */
/* Proxy DLL Entry point                                                */
/*                                                                      */
/************************************************************************/

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, 
                      LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:        
        {
            /*
            if (!GetMsimg32FnAddr())
            {
                OutputDebugString (TEXT("MSIMG32 Proxy: GetMsimg32FnAddr() failed\n"));
                return FALSE;
            }
            */

            OutputDebugString(TEXT("MSIMG32 Proxy: DLL attached\n"));

            // Load injected DLL and execute it's initialization function           
            if (! (hPlugDll = LoadLibrary(pszInjDllName)))
            {
                OutputDebugString (TEXT("MSIMG32 Proxy: Cannot load inject-DLL\n"));
                //return FALSE;
            }

            if (! (pfnInit = (PFNINIT) GetProcAddress (hPlugDll, "Init")))
            {
                OutputDebugString (TEXT("MSIMG32 Proxy: No valid address for executing Init\n"));
                //return FALSE;
            }

            if (pfnInit)
            {
                (*pfnInit)();
            }
            break;
        }

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            if (hMsimg32)
                if (FreeLibrary(hMsimg32))
                    OutputDebugString (TEXT("MSIMG32 Proxy: DLL detached.\n"));
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// 
// Get original MSIMG32.DLL functions virtual addresses
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool GetMsimg32FnAddr()
{
    TCHAR libName[MAX_PATH];
    GetSystemDirectory (libName, MAX_PATH);
    _tcscat_s (libName, MAX_PATH*sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("\\msimg32.dll"));
    hMsimg32 = LoadLibrary (libName);

    if (!hMsimg32)
        return false;

    if ( (pfnVSetDdrawFlag = (PFNVSETDDRAWFLAG) GetProcAddress(hMsimg32, "vSetDdrawflag")) == NULL)
        return false;

    if ( (pfnAlphaBlend = (PFNALPHABLEND) GetProcAddress(hMsimg32, "AlphaBlend")) == NULL)
        return false;

    if ( (pfnDllInitialize = (PFNDLLINITIALIZE) GetProcAddress(hMsimg32, "DllInitialize")) == NULL)
        return false;

    if ( (pfnGradientFill = (PFNGRADIENTFILL) GetProcAddress(hMsimg32, "GradientFill")) == NULL)
        return false;

    if ( (pfnTransparentBlt = (PFNTRANSPARENTBLT) GetProcAddress(hMsimg32, "TransparentBlt")) == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}

//
// Exported function definition
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
BOOL WINAPI TransparentBlt(HDC p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5, HDC p6, int p7, int p8, 
                                   int p9, int p10, UINT p11)
{   
    return pfnTransparentBlt (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11);
}

BOOL WINAPI AlphaBlend(HDC p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5, HDC p6, int p7 , int p8,
                               int p9, int p10, BLENDFUNCTION dw)
{
    return pfnAlphaBlend (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,dw);
}

BOOL WINAPI GradientFill (HDC p1, PTRIVERTEX p2, ULONG p3, PVOID p4, ULONG p5, ULONG p6)
{
    return pfnGradientFill (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllInitialize (HINSTANCE d1,DWORD d2, LPVOID d3)
{
    if (pfnDllInitialize == NULL)
    {
        GetMsimg32FnAddr();
    }

    return pfnDllInitialize (d1, d2, d3);
}

VOID WINAPI vSetDdrawflag (VOID)
{
    (*pfnVSetDdrawFlag)();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you review [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, and specifically, take heed to the comment: **"It is not safe to call LoadLibrary from DllMain"**. You should be demand-loading the API on first-use, protected by a mutex or crit-section.

Comment: How about "demand-loading the API on first-use"? Does it mean that I should Load system msimg32.dll in DLLMain of local msimg32.dll? It really throws exception of access violation. I guess it is a deadlock results from the same DLL name: msimg32.dll. Since I have test another case: load another normal dll other than msimg32.dll in DLLMain, everthing is ok.

Comment: The following content can be found in MSDN-DLLMain:                The entry-point function should perform only simple initialization or termination tasks. It must not call the LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx function (or a function that calls these functions), because this may create dependency loops in the DLL load order. This can result in a DLL being used before the system has executed its initialization code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you're now-loading msimg32.dll from oneof *your* API's rather than DllMain you're doing it right. At this point the only other thing that commonly goes wrong is the calling convention (and of course, the possibility of compiling with the a different platform i.e. x64 vs. x86, but your LoadLibrary would fail if that were the case). Check your calling conventions and make sure they match what the DLL is expecting. One way to do this is to  find a function in msimg32.dll that has NO parameters. If that *works*, your calling convention is most definitely wrong on your other calls.

Comment: Steven, Please look at my first comment. I stated exactly what you copied from MSDN. Perhaps the bold highlight wasn't clear. If you are now *NOT* calling LoadLibrary from DllMain, then you're doing it right. The stack corruption is due either to an incorrect calling convention convention (_stdcall vs _cdecl) or the library has not yet been properly initialized (I would think DllInitialize() has something to do with that), or perhaps both. But regardless, you're no longer loading from DllMain of your ell, so you got that part *right*

Comment: Thanks, LoadLibrary is not accepted in DLLMain().

Comment: Two things to improve:
1. Check the calling convention
   a> set default calling convertion to __stdcall for msimg32.dll and DLL host (A win32 project to test msimg32.dll.
   b> Change "bool GetMsimg32FnAddr()" to "BOOL WINAPI GetMsimg32FnAddr()", also use __stdcall.
unfortunately, all of them do NOT work.

2. To change part of code in GetMsimg32FnAddr() to find the root reason.
change:
   _tcscat_s (libName, MAX_PATH*sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("\\msimg32.dll"));
to:
   _tcscat(libName, _T("\\msimg32.dll"));
Fixed! Thanks a lot. It seems that root cause is not calling convention, but string.

Comment: excellent. glad its up and running.

Comment: The safe  _tcscat_s results in stack crash while unsafe tcscat works. A really strange for visual c++.